# Area of the closed loop in the region $x\ge0$ of $x^4=x^2-y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Consider the planar figure described by the equation $x^4=x^2-y^2$, (which is called the *Lemniscate of Gerono*). It may be conveniently represented by the parametrization $$x(t)=\sin t,\; y(t)=\sin t \cos t,\; 0\le t\le 2\pi $$
Use Green's theorem to find the area of the closed loop in the region $x\ge0$.
(Suggestion: Choose $P(x,y)=0, Q(x,y)=x$)

I don't understand the parametrization and how to set up the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $Q_x-P_y=1$ we have, via green's theorem, that (with the suggested choice)

$$A = \iint\limits_D 1 \,dA = \oint\limits_{C}{{x\,dy}}$$

Your loop is drawn out by $0\le t\le\pi$.

$$A = \oint\limits_{C}{{x\,dy}} = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}{\sin (t)\,d(\sin(t)\cos(t))}$$

$$=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}{\sin (t)(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t))}\ dt$$

Edit: The orientation of the provided trace is clockwise in this case. So you need to negate the final answer. If it were counter-clockwise then it would not be necessary.

Comment: how do we know that the region of the curve st $x\ge 0$ is where $0\le t \le \pi$

Comment: $\sin(t)$, which is $x$, is only non-negative in that interval. You should draw the curve yourself, in any of these exercises to help your understanding

Answer (score 0):

$$x^4=x^2-y^2 \implies y=\pm x \sqrt{1-x^2},$$ So the required area is
$$A=2\int_{0}^{1} x \sqrt{1-x^2} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{u} du= \frac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: The question specified an answer based on Green's theorem. And also asked for an explanation to the parametrization.